# assertion encryption: mcrypt iv size doesnt match extracted string length

Tags: php, encryption, saml, assertion, simplesamlphp

I've been using **simpleSAMLphp** without assertion encryption, and everything was great!
Now I've been asked to accept encrypted assertions, and I'm getting the following warning:

**Warning**: mcrypt_generic_init(): Iv size incorrect; supplied length: 23, needed: 16 in */path/to/myproject/simplesaml/vendor/simplesamlphp/xmlseclibs/xmlseclibs.php on line 454*

Debugging this, I found that **xmlseclibs** is trying to extract the iv string using a **substr**($data, 0, 16), and this is returning a **string(23)**. My first guess was a multibyte issue, but **mb_substr** didn't do the trick either.

I've been debugging this all afternoon, and got nowhere.
Any ideas?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem by setting `mb_func.overload=0`. By default it was 2.